# Having trouble with Amazon Lex in phonegap with audio files

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, audio

I've been working in phonegap for an app i'm building but, the main issue im having is amazon lex. i'm using a media plugin by cordova to record the audio but the file type for the plugin uses is AAC which amazon lex uses PCM or OPUS. Phonegap only lets the user to pick the file and doesn't allow the media plugin to buffer.